# PHP Unit Test Mocking a member variable dependency

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

Hello lets say I want to test the function run from Class A and I'm using [Mockery](https://github.com/mockery/mockery) to mock external dependencies:

```
class A {
    protected myB;

    public function __construct(B $param) {
      $this->myB = $param;
    }

    protected function doStuff() {
      return "done";
    }

    public function run() {
      $this->doStuff();

      $this->myB->doOtherStuff();

      return "finished";
    }
}

class B {
    public function doOtherStuff() {
      return "done";
    }
}
```

So I wrote the test like this:

```
public function testRun() {
    $mockB = Mockery::mock('overload:B');
    $mockB->shouldReceive('doOtherStuff')
        ->andReturn("not done");

    $mockA = Mockery::mock(A::class)->makePartial()->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();
    $mockA->shouldReceive('doStuff')->andReturns("done");
    
    $mockA->run();
}
```

This throws me an exception like this:
Error: Call to a member function doStuff() on null

I tried diffrent variations of mocking the internal dependency B which is getting called in the run function but I always endend up in an exception.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mock the thing you are testing. Inject the mocked `B` into `A`.

```
    public function testRun()
    {
        // Arrange
        $mockB = Mockery::mock(B::class);
        $a = new A($mockB);

        // Assert
        $mockB->shouldReceive('doOtherStuff')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn("not done");

        // Act
        $a->run();
    }
```

If you want to monkey patch `A`, you can still pass the mocked `B` in ([more details: constructor arguments in mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#creating-test-doubles-constructor-arguments)):

```
    public function testRun()
    {
        // Arrange
        $mockB = Mockery::mock(B::class);
        $a     = Mockery::mock(A::class, [$mockB])
            ->makePartial()
            ->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();
        $a->shouldReceive('doStuff')
            ->andReturns('mocked done');

        // Assert
        $mockB->shouldReceive('doOtherStuff')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn('not done');

        // Act
        $a->run();
    }
```

Comment: But what if I explicitly want to mock some functions from A instead of using the real ones?

Comment: Basically the same. You can still inject the dependency. I updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this solution also and it gives me an error like this: Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_4_B::doOtherStuff(), but no expectations were specified

Comment: And if I want to make mockB partial then it tries to call the real doOtherStuff function instead of the mocked one. I really dont understand the bevavior here

Comment: The 4 in `Mockery_4_B` tells me, that there are more mock objects around than in this example. Maybe you've mocked `B` twice and injected a `B` without expectation into `A`. The test case in my answer works well with the classes `A` and `B` shown in your question.